# How to remove white space above and below Tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, floats, technical-drawing

I used GMS package to write a maths book, and used Tikz code genrated by Geogebra to draw the image.

The problem is there are too much white space above and below Tikz figure, as in the following picture:

[image]

Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage[papersize={160mm,240mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .tif}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\begin{document}
This is the document.


\begin{definition}
 Đây là môi trường định nghĩa, và hình vẽ đi ngay sau nó.
 This is the definition environment, and the Tikz figure follows it. 
\end{definition}

 \definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=0.7]
\clip(-4.3,-10.66) rectangle (17.58,6.3);
\draw (-2.3,4.08)-- (-3.74,0.04);
\draw (-3.74,0.04)-- (0.9,0.02);
\draw (0.9,0.02)-- (-2.3,4.08);
\draw (4.88,4.04)-- (3.44,0);
\draw (3.44,0)-- (8.08,-0.02);
\draw (8.08,-0.02)-- (4.88,4.04);
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (-2.3,4.08) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-2.28,4.4) node {$A$};
\fill [color=black] (-3.74,0.04) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-3.78,-0.18) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (0.9,0.02) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1,-0.18) node {$C$};
\draw[color=black] (-1.44,1.52) node {h.1a};
\fill [color=black] (4.88,4.04) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.9,4.36) node {$A$};
\fill [color=black] (3.44,0) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3.4,-0.22) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (8.08,-0.02) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (8.14,-0.26) node {$C=D$};
\draw[color=black] (5.74,1.48) node {h.1b};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}

The above picture is left align also. 
The other question is : How can I center it? 
Please help me. 
\end{document}
```

So, how can I remove that white space? Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example, beginning with `\documentclass`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I added the MWE above. Please help me.

Comment: The `gsm-l` document class is unknown to me.  Where is that located on the web?

Comment: Here it is: ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/private/amslatex/gsm-l-template.tex

Comment: Here is the official link:
http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/monopackages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The offending line in the TikZ code is the first line, which clips the output to the specified rectangle. Normally this is used to trim the bounding box and show only part of a figure, however, in your case, whatever program/code generated the TikZ code has used the `\clip` functionality to *expand* the bounding box (likely to match the view shown in the creating program at the time of code generation).

The solution is simply to comment out the offending `\clip` command. For your other question, you can place the TikZ code inside a proper `figure` environment with `\centering` inside, as I have shown below.

**The Code**

```
    \documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage[papersize={160mm,240mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .tif}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\begin{document}
This is the document.

 Đây là môi trường định nghĩa, và hình vẽ đi ngay sau nó.
 This is the definition environment, and the Tikz figure follows it. 

 \definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
\begin{figure}[h] % place the figure [h]ere, you may want to give LaTeX some more options
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=0.7]
%\clip(-4.3,-10.66) rectangle (17.58,6.3);
\draw (-2.3,4.08)-- (-3.74,0.04);
\draw (-3.74,0.04)-- (0.9,0.02);
\draw (0.9,0.02)-- (-2.3,4.08);
\draw (4.88,4.04)-- (3.44,0);
\draw (3.44,0)-- (8.08,-0.02);
\draw (8.08,-0.02)-- (4.88,4.04);
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (-2.3,4.08) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-2.28,4.4) node {$A$};
\fill [color=black] (-3.74,0.04) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-3.78,-0.18) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (0.9,0.02) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1,-0.18) node {$C$};
\draw[color=black] (-1.44,1.52) node {h.1a};
\fill [color=black] (4.88,4.04) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.9,4.36) node {$A$};
\fill [color=black] (3.44,0) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3.4,-0.22) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (8.08,-0.02) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (8.14,-0.26) node {$C=D$};
\draw[color=black] (5.74,1.48) node {h.1b};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is the figure caption.}
\end{figure}

The above picture is left align also. 
The other question is : How can I center it? 
Please help me. 
\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Some more explanations on how to detect the problem. The command `\clip` clips the picture part that that lies within the rectangle bounded by `(-4.3,-10.66)` and `(17.58,6.3)`. To get a visual of this rectangle you can add some sort of grid like

```
\draw (-5,-10) grid (18,6.5);
%\clip(-4.3,-10.66) rectangle (17.58,6.3);
```

in your `tikzpicture` and you will get

[image]

Now you will see that the `\clip` operation is doing a bad thing by un-necessarily showing the bottom, top and right parts. Hence as told by Paul Gessler the culprit is the dimensions given to the `\clip` command. You can either comment out the `\clip` line or choose a proper dimension to have a more tighter border.

For the latter, we can assign the tick labels to see the correct labels. Add

```
\draw[help lines,xstep=1,ystep=1] (-5,-10) grid (18,6.5);
\foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,18} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\x}; }
\foreach \y in {-10,-9,...,6} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\y}; }
```

to get

[image]

Now you can see the correct coordinates that musrt be provided to the `\clip` operation.
I will choose `(-4,-0.5) rectangle (9,4.5);` in

```
\clip(-4,-0.5) rectangle (9,4.5);
\draw[help lines,xstep=1,ystep=1] (-5,-10) grid (18,6.5);
\foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,18} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\x}; }
\foreach \y in {-10,-9,...,6} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\y}; }
```

to get

[image]

Finally comment out the grids and friends like

```
\clip(-4,-0.5) rectangle (9,4.5);
%\draw[help lines,xstep=1,ystep=1] (-5,-10) grid (18,6.5);
%\foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,18} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\x}; }
%\foreach \y in {-10,-9,...,6} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\y}; }
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={160mm,240mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .tif}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\begin{document}
This is the document.

 Đây là môi trường định nghĩa, và hình vẽ đi ngay sau nó.
 This is the definition environment, and the Tikz figure follows it.

 \definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
\begin{figure}[h] % place the figure [h]ere, you may want to give LaTeX some more options
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=0.7]
\clip(-4,-0.5) rectangle (9,4.5);
%\draw[help lines,xstep=1,ystep=1] (-5,-10) grid (18,6.5);
%\foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,18} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\x}; }
%\foreach \y in {-10,-9,...,6} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\y}; }
\draw (-2.3,4.08)-- (-3.74,0.04);
\draw (-3.74,0.04)-- (0.9,0.02);
\draw (0.9,0.02)-- (-2.3,4.08);
\draw (4.88,4.04)-- (3.44,0);
\draw (3.44,0)-- (8.08,-0.02);
\draw (8.08,-0.02)-- (4.88,4.04);
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (-2.3,4.08) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-2.28,4.4) node {$A$};
\fill [color=black] (-3.74,0.04) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-3.78,-0.18) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (0.9,0.02) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1,-0.18) node {$C$};
\draw[color=black] (-1.44,1.52) node {h.1a};
\fill [color=black] (4.88,4.04) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.9,4.36) node {$A$};
\fill [color=black] (3.44,0) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3.4,-0.22) node {$B$};
\fill [color=black] (8.08,-0.02) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (8.14,-0.26) node {$C=D$};
\draw[color=black] (5.74,1.48) node {h.1b};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is the figure caption.}
\end{figure}

The above picture is left align also.
The other question is : How can I center it?
Please help me.
\end{document}
```

[image]